# Select two map layers with 1 click

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Is it possible to select two Google map polygon layers with 1 click.  I am able to add two layers: buildings and parcels.   I can access each layer individually, but if I click on the map where the building is on top of the parcel layer, only the building layer is retrieved.

script to add layers:

```
 var otrParcel = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'Geometry'",
      from: otrParcLayer 
    },
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });

  var otrBuilding = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'Geometry'",
      from: otrBldgLayer
    },
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });
```

I am trying to retrieve the infoWindoHtml from both layers with 1 click.  This works for building and parcel seperately, but not when 1 is on top of the other.  Attached is my latest attempt at trying to do this.  The first listener function is not working properly when I click on a building with a parcel.  The second listener function is working properly.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(otrBuilding , 'click', function(e) {
    var  infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      maxWidth: 300
    });
    infoBubble.addTab('Building', e.infoWindowHtml );

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: "'geometry'",
        from: otrParcLayer,
        where: "ST_INTERSECTS('geometry', CIRCLE(LATLNG(e.latLng), 0.001))",
        limit:1
      } 
    });

    infoBubble.addTab('Parcel', layer.infoWindowHtml);  

    infoBubble.addTab('Contact', contacInfo() );
    if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
      infoBubble.setPosition(e.latLng);
      infoBubble.open(map);
    };
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(otrParcel , 'click', function(e) {
    var  infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      maxWidth: 300
    });
    infoBubble.addTab('Parcel', e.infoWindowHtml);
    infoBubble.addTab('Contact', contacInfo() );
    if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
      infoBubble.setPosition(e.latLng);
      infoBubble.open(map);
    };
  });
```

here is a link to the page I am testing.  When map loads, the building to lower right (Emery theater) is what I am using for testing.  It has a donut hole in the middle.  Clicking on the outer ring should include the building and parcel information (which it doesn't).  Clicking in the middle will only show parcel information.

http://fitreks.com/bdcurc/bdcurcMUmockup11.html

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set {clickable: false} on both layers.  Then use a map click listener to query both tables for the data to populate the InfoBubble (rather than using the data available in the FusionTablesLayer click listener) and popluate the InfoBubble with the data from the callback functions of both queries (where applicable).  You may want to consider using a single InfoBubble rather letting multiple ones stay open.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried setting clickable:false for top layer (building) on initialize. Then set clickable:true during google.maps.event.addListener(otrParcel , 'click', function(e){.  My thought is the next time I clicked the building it would run google.maps.event.addListener(otrBuilding , 'click', function(e){.  But this did not work.  It continued to go to otrParcel.    I want to use the layers rather than callback functions so that I have access to the infoWindowHtml.  This allows someone else to manage infoWindow styling through Fusion table UI.

Answer (score 0):

You may trigger the click event on the underlying layer.

Don't forget to use the e-argument as 3rd argument for trigger, otherwise the event-argument is not available inside the callback.

---

## edit:

Example: currently the layer otrBuilding is on top, so you must trigger there onclick the click-event for the otrParcel-layer:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(otrBuilding , 'click', function(e) {
   google.maps.event.trigger(otrParcel , 'click',e);

   //continue with your code
});
```

But it looks like it would be better, when you put the parcel-layer on top, an trigger the event for the building-layer when the parcel-layer has been clicked:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(otrParcel , 'click', function(e) {
   google.maps.event.trigger(otrBuilding , 'click',e);

   //continue with your code
});
```

Please note: the e-argument contains the event-object for the click on the top-layer. This is no problem when you only access lat and lng of the event, but you will not be able to use the event to access properties related to the layer like `e.row`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, but am unsure on how to do this for the underlying layer.  I keep getting the top layer.

Comment: I am trying to access the properties related to the layer such as e.row.  I was hoping I could use the e.infoWindowHtml for each layer and set each up in a different tab in an infoBubble.  From what what you have stated and what I have tried this is not possible yet.

Comment: This creates recursion, both layers are triggering each other infinitely. :(